# неадекватный total при пагинации springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, pagination

при различных параметрах size получаю разный total.

при size > количество элементов, total верный

при size <= количество элементов, total неверный

```
public GenericPage<FilterUserDto> getAllUserIds(@RequestParam(value = "fullTextQuery", required = false) String fullTextQuery,
                                                @ApiIgnore Pageable pageable) {
    Page<FilterUserDto> allUserIds = statisticsService.getAllUserIds(fullTextQuery, pageable);
    return new GenericPage<>(allUserIds.getContent(), allUserIds.getTotalElements());
}
```

верный тотал:

```
tasks/background/orgs/allUserIds?size=13
{"id":"JTC_SergeySV2_AdminDBO2","name":"JTC_SergeySV2_AdminDBO2"},{"id":"cf981379-68ed-42b0-b283-c733af367c6a","name":"system"}],"total":12}
```

неверный тотал:

```
tasks/background/orgs/allUserIds?size=12
{"id":"JTC_SergeySV2_AdminDBO2","name":"JTC_SergeySV2_AdminDBO2"},{"id":"cf981379-68ed-42b0-b283-c733af367c6a","name":"system"}],"total":2914}
```

сервис:

```
public Page<FilterUserDto> getAllUserIds(String fullTextQuery, Pageable pageable) {
    return taskRepository.getTaskUsers(formatFullTextQuery(fullTextQuery), pageable)
            .map(u -> new FilterUserDto(u.getId(), u.getName()));
}
```

репозиторий:

```
@Query(" SELECT distinct t.user " +
        " FROM Task t " +
        " WHERE :fullTextQuery is null or UPPER(t.user.name) like :fullTextQuery" +
        " order by t.user.name")
Page<User> getTaskUsers(@Param("fullTextQuery") String fullTextQuery, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, каким образом формируется запрос к БД.

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил слой сервиса и репозиторий

Comment: Насколько вижу, в запросе есть join и используется distinct, а с ними пагинация не будет работать корректно (по крайней мере у меня так и было). У аннотации `@Query` есть параметр countQuery, который необходимо переопределить и указать правильный запрос на определение количества нужных элементов. [Пример как это делается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70123813/6752984)